# Is there a way to query for all locations (a list of polygons stored as geojson) fully covering given polygon with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, polygon, geospatial, geojson

I have a list of polygons stored as geoJson inside MongoDB.
Example of one of the polygons:
{
 "Area" : "Area123",
 "Boundary" : {
    "type" : "Polygon",
    "coordinates" : [[[100,12],[120,12],[120,15],[100,12]]]
  }
}
Boundary is a 2dsphere index.

Using $geoWithin, I am able to specify a bigger polygon and return Area123 which lies fully within this bigger polygon.

Is there a way to specify a smaller polygon that lies within Area123 and let MongoDB returns Area123?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$geoIntersects](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/) who specifically looks for polygon intersecting other ones. You can do something like this:

```
db.<collection>.find( { Boundary :
                         { $geoIntersects :
                            { $geometry :
                               { type : "Polygon"
                                 coordinates : [ <coordinates of Area123> ]
                      } } } } )
```

However this query will return even polygons who doesn't contains `Area123` but also those who are inside, those who intersect a bit, etc.

So you can check if Area123 points, for each returned Polygon, are contained inside.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that's what I wanted, to get all polygons containing, within and intersecting a bit! $geoIntersects works perfectly!